# SciChart - Not all chart panes zoom correctly

Tags: wpf, scichart

I have a TabControl that contains a dynamic number of chart panes via an ItemsControl. Inside the ItemsControl’s ItemsTemplate is a single ScichartSurface with bindings to the RenderableSeries, XAxis, YAxes, and VerticalChartGroup.

The xaml looks something like this:

```
<s:SciChartSurface name="Chart" RenderableSeries="{Binding rSeries}" XAxis="{Binding xAxis}" YAxes="{Binding yAxes}" s:SciChartGroup.VerticalChartGroup="{Binding vGroup}">
```

Within the surface, I have a ModifierGroup that contains (in order) a RubberbandXyZoomModifier (XAxisOnly), MouseWheelZoomModifier, ZoomPanModifier, ZoomExtentsModifier, and a custom mod call TimeSegmentSelectionModifier. All of these modifiers have their ReceiveHandledEvents property set to True, they are all under the same MouseEventGroup, and they all seem to work fine under normal circumstances.

Note: The Rubberband and TimeSegment modifiers are inversely set to Enabled. Meaning, only one of them functions at a time.

My issue is primarily with the RubberBand Mod:

Let’s say I have 5 chart panes being displayed and I want to zoom in; If I click and drag within the 3rd chart, every chart zooms correctly.
If I click withing the 3rd chart, drag the mouse outside of that chart (anywhere else on my screen) and let go, then only charts 1, 2, and 3 are zoomed correctly. Charts 4 and 5 won’t budge and act as if I had merely zoomed to extents.

This happens with any number of chart panes and the issue occurs on whatever pane I happened to be zooming in on.

I’ve been troubleshooting this issue for a few days now and I don’t know where else to look.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I'd seen this earlier but the problem that you are describing [is solved here](https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/synchronize-charts-without-xaml):

> In order to synchronize two charts, you need to perform the following steps:
>
> Set the MouseManager.MouseEventGroup attached property on the root SciChartSurface.ChartModifier. This synchronizes the mouse events between two or more charts which share the same MouseEventGroup ID.
>
> Set the SciChartGroup.VerticalChartGroup attached property on the SciChartSurface itself. This synchronizes the sizes of the YAxis on multiple charts so that the charts line up
>
> Bind the XAxis.VisibleRanges together. This ensures that the charts are always in sync as you zoom / pan (eliminates rounding error).
>   These are demonstrated in our example [Synchronize Multi Chart Mouse](https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-chart-example-sync-multi-chart-mouse/).

Often people miss the last step (Binding the Axis Visible Ranges together). Is this the case in your example?

We have a tutorial covering synchronising multiple charts here:

- [Sync Multi Chart tutorial (code-behind)](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Tutorial%2009%20-%20Linking%20Multiple%20Charts.html)
- [Sync Multi Chart tutorial (MVVM)](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Tutorial%2009b%20-%20Linking%20Multiple%20Charts%20with%20MVVM.html)

Github source for tutorials can be found at https://github.com/abtsoftware/scichart.wpf.examples under the Tutorials folder.